# JS: function waiting by calling itself with settimout - how to handle parmeters?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I want a function in pure JS to wait and execute only when a certain condition happens.

```
function wait_then_go  (a,b,c) {

if (!go) window.setTimeout (wait_then_go (a,b,c), 500);

// go here 

}
```

Is there a general way to pass the arguments in the timeout instead of specifying a,b,c ?
I dont want the code to break if I chnage the arguments on the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arguments` if you don't wanna specify `a,b,c`. and also use the wrapper function and call arguments inside that.

```
function wait_then_go  (a,b,c) {
    const arg = [...arguments];
    if (!go) window.setTimeout (() => wait_then_go (...args), 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function `wait_then_go` into `setTimeout` callback function, and pass `...arguments` as params.

```
function wait_then_go  (a,b,c) {
  if (!go) window.setTimeout (function() {
    wait_then_go (...arguments)
  }, 500);
  // go here 
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have repeated a,b,c in the call so that does not answer my question.